How can I add specific cells from one DataGridView in form2 to another DataGridView in form1
I am working on a .NET 8, C#, SQL Server project which is a stock management system.
My issue is: I have a DataGridView in one form which is used to save invoices like this screenshot:
enter image description here
When I double-click on the cell rounded with a red marker, it pops up another form with another DataGridView containing all the products I have in the database and I use to add to the invoice.
And when I double-click on a row in the second DataGridView, I want the first two columns in the DataGridView to be added to the DataGridView in the first form - like in this screenshot:
enter image description here
Here is my code - for the first, main form:
using System.Windows.Forms;

public partial class NewPurchaseInvoiceView : Form
{
    public NewPurchaseInvoiceView()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void ItemsGridList_CellDoubleClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.ColumnIndex == ItemsGridList.Columns["IDColumn"].Index && e.RowIndex >= 0)
        {
            ItemsSelectionModeView itemsSelectionModeView = new ItemsSelectionModeView();
            itemsSelectionModeView.ShowDialog();
        }
    }
}

For the second form, where I choose products from:
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace HMLalpha.Views
{
    public partial class ItemsSelectionModeView : Form
    {
        public ItemsSelectionModeView()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void ItemsSelectionModeView_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            DataTable dataTable = ItemsController.PROCEDURE_DISPLAYALLITEMS();
            ItemsListGridView.Rows.Clear();

            foreach (DataRow dataRow in dataTable.Rows)
            {
                ItemsListGridView.Rows.Add(dataRow[0], dataRow[1], dataRow[2], dataRow[3], dataRow[7], dataRow[4], dataRow[5], dataRow[6]);
            }
        }

        private void ItemSearchTextBox_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            DataTable dataTable = ItemsController.PROCEDURE_SEARCHITEMS(ItemSearchTextBox.Text);
            ItemsListGridView.Rows.Clear();

            foreach (DataRow dataRow in dataTable.Rows)
            {
                ItemsListGridView.Rows.Add(dataRow[1], dataRow[2], dataRow[3], dataRow[7], dataRow[4], dataRow[5], dataRow[6]);
            }
        }

        public void ItemsListGridView_CellDoubleClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
        {
            NewPurchaseInvoiceView newPurchaseInvoiceView = new NewPurchaseInvoiceView();

            foreach (DataGridViewRow dataGridViewRow in ItemsListGridView.SelectedRows)
            {
                newPurchaseInvoiceView.ItemsGridList.Rows.Add(dataGridViewRow.Cells[1].Value.ToString(), 
                    dataGridViewRow.Cells[2].Value.ToString());
            }
            this.Close();
        }   
    }
}

Sorry for the long post. Appreciate any help.
Everything works fine, but the problem is that when I choose the product to add, nothing is added in the first form, and the datagridview is still blank

You cannot do this: NewPurchaseInvoiceView newPurchaseInvoiceView = new NewPurchaseInvoiceView();; this Form is a new instance of the class you're already showing, and it has nothing to do with it. You can add a public method to NewPurchaseInvoiceView that allows to set the data of its DataGridView. Add a Constructor to ItemsSelectionModeView that accepts an instance of NewPurchaseInvoiceView, so you can pass the current instance of the latter when you create the instance of the former -- This kind of question has been asked a many, many times

You can directly pass the Datasource of the DataGridView from Form1 to Form2 via the constructor by declaring it. I assume you are using a DataTable as the Datasource.
Form1:
private void ItemsGridList_CellDoubleClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.ColumnIndex == ItemsGridList.Columns["IDColumn"].Index && e.RowIndex >= 0)
    {
        DataTable Data = ItemsGridList.DataSource as DataTable;
        ItemsSelectionModeView itemsSelectionModeView = new ItemsSelectionModeView(Data);
        itemsSelectionModeView.ShowDialog();
    }
}

Form 2: You can do it as follows by declaring a DataTable variable to receive the value.
 private DataTable Data;
 public ItemsSelectionModeView(DataTable dt)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.Data = dt;
    }

At this point, your new DataTable Data is receiving input from the DataTable in Form1. You can handle it by directly adding data to it.
 public void ItemsListGridView_CellDoubleClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        NewPurchaseInvoiceView newPurchaseInvoiceView = new NewPurchaseInvoiceView();

        foreach (DataGridViewRow dataGridViewRow in ItemsListGridView.SelectedRows)
        {
            DataRow dr =Data.NewRow();
            
            dr["YourFieldNameNeed"]= dataGridViewRow.Cells[1].Value.ToString(); 
                dr["YourFieldNameNeed2"]= dataGridViewRow.Cells[2].Value.ToString(); 
            Data.Rows.Add(dr);
        }
        this.Close();
    }   

You can try it.
